# How to add class from two different css files in wordpress theme?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, bootstrap-5

So, I'm using wp_enqueue_style to add two css files in one function. However, the problem is that when I call a class, the only thing that can be added is a class that comes from one of the files. The class is like overriding another class.

Here is my code:

```
<a class="navbar-brand py-2 anti-white" href="<?= esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>">TES</a>
<!-- anti-white is from style.css and can't be used -->
```

```
function add_theme_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap.min.css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/framework/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css', array( 'style'), '1.7', 'all');

    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap.bundle.min.js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/framework/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array('jquery'), 1.1, true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts');
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding `!important` in css.